# Input encoding in RNNs

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks

I'm working on developing a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) that performs the following task: there are 4 lights, and during each trial, one of them is turned on, followed by another one. The goal is to make a decision based on the combination of lights. Below is an example of a trial.

[image]

I'm wondering about encoding the input data for the RNN: Should I represent the first and second instances of a light turning on using the same 4 dimensions, or should I represent them separately, i.e. using 8 dimensions?